# Java method keeps giving me: "cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors

I'm trying to code a deciphering program. I looked all over but I cannot figure out what is giving me the error. The code is supposed to take user Input, take a number (labeled key), then shift all characters in the string by that number. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class Assignment3 {

    public static void decipher(int key, String scanInput)
    {
         
          for (int x = 0; x < scanInput.length(); x++) {
            int letterDecode = abc.indexOf(scanInput.charAt(x)) + key;
            deciphered = deciphered + abc.charAt(letterDecode); 
            
            }    
            System.out.println(deciphered);
    
    } 
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    
      Scanner scan = new scanner(System.in);
      String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvdxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUPWXYZ";
      String deciphered = "";
      
      
      System.out.println("Please enter your code below");
      String scanInput = scan.nextLine();
      
      System.out.println("Please enter your key (Preferrable from 1-26");
      int key = scan.nextInt();
      
      decipher();        
           
    }
}
```

These are the errors:

```
     Assignment3.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
                int letterDecode = abc.indexOf(scanInput.charAt(x)) + key;
                                   ^
      symbol:   variable abc
      location: class Assignment3
    Assignment3.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                deciphered = deciphered + abc.charAt(letterDecode); 
                ^
      symbol:   variable deciphered
      location: class Assignment3
    Assignment3.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                deciphered = deciphered + abc.charAt(letterDecode); 
                             ^
      symbol:   variable deciphered
      location: class Assignment3
    Assignment3.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
                deciphered = deciphered + abc.charAt(letterDecode); 
                                          ^
      symbol:   variable abc
      location: class Assignment3
    Assignment3.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
                System.out.println(deciphered);
                                   ^
      symbol:   variable deciphered
      location: class Assignment3
    Assignment3.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
          Scanner scan = new scanner(System.in);
                             ^
      symbol:   class scanner
      location: class Assignment3
    Assignment3.java:43: error: method decipher in class Assignment3 cannot be applied to given types;
          decipher();
          ^
      required: int,String
      found: no arguments
      reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
    7 errors
```

Comment: It looks like the code is trying to reference variables that are not within the scope of the method `decipher`

Comment: This does not even compile, I doubt that you ever got an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: java is case-sensitive. `new scanner(...)` does not work if you want to use `Scanner`.

Comment: move the whole body of the `decipher` method to the bottom of your `main` method and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to declare **abc** and **deciphered** variables in *decipher* method.
Moreover do not forget to pass  **key** and **scanInput** variables in your method(last line in the main method).
Please see the following example:

```
public static void decipher(int key, String scanInput)
{
    String abc = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvdxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUPWXYZ";
    String deciphered = "";
    for (int x = 0; x < scanInput.length(); x++) {
        int letterDecode = abc.indexOf(scanInput.charAt(x)) + key;
        deciphered = deciphered + abc.charAt(letterDecode);

    }
    System.out.println(deciphered);

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Please enter your code below");
    String scanInput = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter your key (Preferrable from 1-26");
    int key = scan.nextInt();

    decipher(key, scanInput);
}
```